# Future of Java and JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I just want to know if there are any future for Java and JavaFx. Reason i ask cos' so many programming language keeps popping up. Please advise.

Comment: Great peril leads to great reward.

Comment: "advice" is a noun; "advise" is a verb.

Comment: Programmer related http://bit.ly/aYA9hS

Answer (score 2):

Here is the **TIOBE Programming Community Index for July 2010**:

http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

You can see, Java is still the best followed by C which some folks out there say it is such a dinosaur these days.

Agree with Rafe Kettler, languages don't die.

About JavaFX, have no idea now since I haven't use an application written in it yet but I am curious to know about its future, please let me know also.

Comment: Languages do die, you will eventually see this. All things come to an end.

Answer (score 1):

I think Java's chances are as good as those of FORTRAN, COBOL, and LISP.

I can't predict Java's future any better than I can tell whether or not I'll get hit by a bus tomorrow.  Can you?

Comment: My money is on you not getting hit by a bus tomorrow and Java having a strong presence for at least the next 10 years.  Let me know how I do.

Comment: Made it to work today - so far, so good.  Just ten more years to go!

Answer (score 1):

There are still plenty of jobs in COBOL:

http://www.itjobswatch.co.uk/jobs/uk/cobol.do

And [COBOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL) has been around since 1959.

But some languages and platforms do die out e.g. [G-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code), [DBase IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase) and [CP/M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) - those were the days! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that Java has a pretty good chance of continuing to exist. Java has always been great for web applications, so on and so forth. And like previous posters have mentioned, languages don't die: look at C, Fortran, etc. which have continued to exist for many decades in their fields of "core competency."
I think that Java will see consistent use as Javascript is as possible as ever, especially since Google has built the Android and AJAX APIs around Java or derivative languages.
That said, Java may need a reboot (much like C needed objects, so they made C++). So we may be seeing a J++ soon (not the stupid MS version, but a good, open source one)

Answer (score 0):

You're kidding right?  I wouldn't bet on JavaFX but Java?  There is so much software written with Java of course there is a future.  And which programming languages are you referring to that 'keep popping up'?  Languages that run on the Java VM?  Ruby?  Python?  (Ruby and Python have been around as long or longer (in the case of Python) than Java).